# Cycle detected in recursive async function

Tags: recursion, rust, async-await

I'm trying to find files with an extension in a dir recursively, and here's my current implementation:

```rust
use futures::future::BoxFuture;
use futures::Stream;
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::result;
use tokio::fs::read_dir;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream;

type Result<T> = result::Result<T, std::io::Error>;
type FileNameStream = Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<String>> + Send + Sync + 'static>>;

async fn list_all(root_path: String, ext: String) -> Result<FileNameStream> {
    async fn one_level(path: String, tx: Sender<Result<String>>, ext: String) -> Result<()> {
        let mut dir = read_dir(path).await?;
        let mut files: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

        while let Some(child) = dir.next_entry().await? {
            if let Some(child_path) = child.path().to_str() {
                if child.metadata().await?.is_dir() {
                    tokio::spawn(async {
                        one_level(child_path.to_string(), tx.clone(), ext.clone()).await;
                    });
                } else {
                    if child_path.ends_with(&ext.clone()) {
                        files.push(child_path.to_string())
                    }
                }
            } else {
                tx.send(Err(std::io::Error::new(
                    ErrorKind::Other,
                    "Invalid path".to_string(),
                )));
            }
        }

        for file in files {
            tx.send(Ok(file));
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    let (tx, rx): (Sender<Result<String>>, Receiver<Result<String>>) = channel(2);
    tokio::spawn(async {
        one_level(root_path, tx, ext).await;
    });
    Ok(Box::pin(ReceiverStream::new(rx)))
}
```

I don't quite understand why the compiler complains:

```
14 |     async fn one_level(path: String, tx: Sender<Result<String>>, ext: String) -> Result<()> {
   |                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...which requires borrow-checking `list_all::{closure#0}::one_level`...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
.....
.....
   = note: ...which requires evaluating trait selection obligation `for<'r, 's, 't0> {std::future::ResumeTy, &'r str, std::string::String, &'s tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>, &'t0 std::string::String, impl futures::Future, ()}: std::marker::Send`...
   = note: ...which again requires computing type of `list_all::{closure#0}::one_level::{opaque#0}`, completing the cycle
   = note: cycle used when evaluating trait selection obligation `{std::future::ResumeTy, std::string::String, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>, impl futures::Future, ()}: std::marker::Send`
```

Is it possible to define such a recursive function as async? Can I parallel the procedure of listing dir through `tokio::spwan` and get speed up?

Comment: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/04_recursion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rust async functions are compiled to state machines, so having an async function calling itself will require the state machine to embed itself in its own definition, which would be an infinite recursion.

This is better explained [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/04_recursion.html). The work-araound as explained in the already linked document is to introduce an indirection via `Box` (the `BoxFuture` type) and a non-async function:

```
use futures::future::BoxFuture;
use futures::{FutureExt, Stream};
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::result;
use tokio::fs::read_dir;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream;

type Result<T> = result::Result<T, std::io::Error>;
type FileNameStream = Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<String>> + Send + Sync + 'static>>;

async fn list_all(root_path: String, ext: String) -> Result<FileNameStream> {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<Result<String>>, Receiver<Result<String>>) = channel(2);
    tokio::spawn(async {
        recursive(root_path, tx, ext).await.unwrap();
    });
    Ok(Box::pin(ReceiverStream::new(rx)))
}

fn recursive(
    path: String,
    tx: Sender<Result<String>>,
    ext: String,
) -> BoxFuture<'static, Result<()>> {
    async move {
        let mut dir = read_dir(path).await?;
        let mut files: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

        while let Some(child) = dir.next_entry().await? {
            match child.path().to_str() {
                Some(child_path) => {
                    let metadata = child.metadata().await?;

                    if metadata.is_dir() {
                        let cp = child_path.to_owned();
                        let tx = tx.clone();
                        let ext = ext.clone();

                        tokio::spawn(async {
                            recursive(cp, tx, ext).await.unwrap();
                        });
                    } else {
                        if child_path.ends_with(&ext) {
                            files.push(child_path.to_owned())
                        }
                    }
                }
                None => {
                    tx.send(Err(std::io::Error::new(
                        ErrorKind::Other,
                        "Invalid path".to_string(),
                    )))
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
                }
            }
        }

        for file in files {
            tx.send(Ok(file)).await.unwrap();
        }
        Ok(())
    }
    .boxed()
}
```

PS: I've also fixed some other issues with your code, such as missing `await` on the `tx.send()` calls - remember - futures  perform work only when they are polled!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Could you please explain why `unwrap` on the result inside `tokio::spawn` and `tx.send(Ok).await`? will they just panic the whole program or just a thread/executor that runs it? Is it possible to catch and propogates the errors as well and send to the channel?

Comment: Unwrapping them will cause a panic and thus crash the app in case of error.  You have to decide how/if to handle the error cases. Usually it's much better to fail/crash as early as possible instead of working with incorrect data

Comment: What's the idiomatic way to deal with `SendError`? Should we propagate it if we are writing an app that loops for user input and does various handling? Or we should just panic since that means buggy code we wrote?

Comment: The error is returned when the `Receiver` has been dropped, thus it's not possible to receive any messages. If it's not possible to happen in your app then unwrapping it is fine. But if it's possibel to happen, the proper way to handle the error depends on what should happen when there is no longer a receiver - there is no generic solution - it depends on the app